# "undefined reference to memcpy" during u-boot-spl build. How can I use the archtecture assisted memcpy?

Tags: embedded-linux, arm64, u-boot

When I build u-boot-spl for our board, I see these link errors.  (u-boot version v2021.10, commit 50c84208ad, Tom Rini, Oct 4 2021)

```
u-boot/common/spl/spl.c:669: undefined reference to `memcpy'
u-boot/common/spl/spl.c:684: undefined reference to `mem_malloc_init'
...
```

But arch/arm/Kconfig says (my board is ARM64)

```
config USE_ARCH_MEMCPY
    bool "Use an assembly optimized implementation of memcpy"
    default y if !ARM64
    depends on !ARM64 || (ARM64 && (GCC_VERSION >= 90400))
    help
      Enable the generation of an optimized version of memcpy.
      Such an implementation may be faster under some conditions
      but may increase the binary size.
```

So if ARM64 and GCC version is later then 9.04, USE_ARCH_MEMCPY should be turned on.
And in my case, I can check in include/config/auto.conf the two condition is true.

```
CONFIG_ARM64=y
CONFIG_GCC_VERSION=100201
```

But USE_ARCH_MEMCPY doesn't appare in include/cofig/auto.conf (is this normal?).
Anyway, I think this CONFIG_USE_ARCH_MEMCPY should be `y`.  Why does it give me this memcpy undefined error?

I checked in lib/Makefile, I see

```
obj-y += string.o
```

which is unconditional and this string.c contains memcpy function. But of course this function is enclosed by #ifndef __HAVE_ARCH_MEMCPY, so it's not what I want anyway.

Is there any option I should turn on to make use of this hardware assisted memcpy?
ADD : I tried adding CONFIG_LTO but it didn't work.

Comment: Based on previous posts you've made in these topics, I suspect there's some problems with the Kconfig entries you've created around your SoC or board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched the Kconfig files and found there are CONFIG_USE_ARCH_MEMCPY, CONFIG_SPL_USE_ARCH_MEMCPY, CONFIG_USE_ARCH_MEMSET, CONFIG_SPL_USE_ARCH_MEMSET, etc. So I made those configs to be selected for my board. And those errors are gone (with CONFIG_LTO-link time optimization is set so that stdlib is not used). I still have some more 'undefined' errors for strncmp, timer_init, puts, hang, mem_malloc_init etc. I'm not sure I can fix the errors using similar methods or this approach is the correct, advisable method. And if I prefer software routine, what should I do?
Waiting for a better answer.
**ADD (2021. 11. 29) :**
Ovidiu Panait from u-boot email list told me I can remove some 'undefined symbol' error by setting CONFIG_SPL_LIBGENERIC_SUPPORT and CONFIG_SPL_LIBCOMMON_SUPPORT to 'y'. After setting this I found those memcpy, memset link errors are also gone without setting USE_ARCH_xxx or USE_SPL_ARCH_xxx configs.